# How to get slice of string in OCaml?

Tags: json, string, ocaml, slice

So I'm writing a JSON parser in OCaml, and I need to get a slice of a string. More specifically, I need to get the first n characters of a string so I can pattern-match with them.

Here's an example string:

```
"null, \"field2\": 25}"
```

So, how could I use just a couple lines of OCaml code to get just the first 4 characters (the `null`)?

P.S. I've already thought about using something like `input.[0..4]` but I'm not entirely sure how that works, I'm reasonably new to OCaml and the ML family.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the standard library documentation? There's a `String.sub` function there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using build-in `sub` function should do the work:

```
let example_string = "null, \"field2\": 25}"
(*val example_string : string = "null, \"field2\": 25}" *)
let first_4 = String.sub example_string 0 4
(*val first_4 : string = "null" *)
```

I suggest you to look at official documentation:
https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/String.html

And if you are not doing this for self teaching I would strongly suggest using one of available libraries for the purpose, such as *yojson* (https://ocaml-community.github.io/yojson/yojson/Yojson/index.html) for example.